# Where should I ask questions about Stata?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am having trouble graphing a data set in [Stata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stata). In which Stack Exchange site would I find an appropriate answer?

Comment: I read that as 'Where should I ask questions about Santa' :)

Comment: Yes, Virginia, there is a Santa Claus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ask certain questions about "Stata" at our [*Cross Validated*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions), [*Economics*](https://economics.stackexchange.com/), [*Data Science*](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) and Stack Overflow sites, where there's over 400 results for "[[Stata] graphing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstata%5D+graphing)". All these sites even have a tag for Stata.

Just make sure to go through the help centre of each of the sites to know where your question would be best suited.

Comment: Cross Validated will only accept it if it has a statistical question as programming questions are off-topic there.